# Puppet - IF statement using custom fact does not work

Tags: if-statement, puppet, facter

The if statement doesn't work using a custom fact, i try this :

```
notify { "FACTER value= ${facts['versionrepokubelocal']}": }
if $facts['versionrepokubelocal'] !=  '2' {
  notify { "Upgrading repository version": }
}
```

I use notify before "if" for to check the value of the custom fact.
Trying with puppet apply (same with puppet agent -t on remote server) get the following output :

```
Notice: FACTER versionrepokubelocal value = 2
Notice: /Stage[main]/Kube::Config/Notify[FACTER versionrepokubelocal value = 2]/message: defined    'message' as 'FACTER versionrepokubelocal value = 2'
Debug: /Stage[main]/Kube::Config/Notify[FACTER versionrepokubelocal value = 2]: The container   Class[Kube::Config] will propagate my refresh event
Notice: Upgrading repository version
Notice: /Stage[main]/Kube::Config/Notify[Upgrading repository version]/message: defined 'message' as  'Upgrading repository version'
```

Before and after the execution I checked the value of the custom fact on the server and it is correctly valued as above :

[root@myserver manifests]$ facter versionrepokubelocal
2

I can't understand why it doesn't work correctly if the fact is correctly valued and the syntax of the statement is correct (tested with pdk validate and pdk test unit), it should not print "Upgrading repository version".

Answer (score 1):

The value of that facter looks like numeric so if it is numeric change your if condition with out quotes for value like below

```
if $facts['versionrepokubelocal'] !=  2 {   
  notify { "Upgrading repository version": } 
}
```

Comment: This is a likely explanation.  The docs [explicitly specify](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/lang_expressions#lang_exp_comparison_operators-comparison-equality) that `==` (and therefore `!=`) takes data type into account.  They give the specific example that `1 == "1"` evaluates to false.

Comment: But note: "facter" is a program.  The data it generates are called *facts*, as in "the value of that fact".